# Alphabetical order problem in bibliography

Tags: bibtex, natbib

I am using BibTeX (with `natbib`) and I have a file `mybib.bib` with the following reference:

```
@Article{DPMN92,
author = {G. Da Prato and P. Malliavin and D. Nualart},
title = {Compact families of Wiener functionals},
journal = {C. R. Acad. Sci. Paris},
year = {1992},
OPTkey = {•},
volume = {315},
number = {S\'{e}rie I},
pages = {1287--1291},
OPTmonth = {•},
OPTnote = {•},
OPTannote = {•}
}
```

Then I have many more. The problem is that this reference is ordered as "P" and not as "D". I have tried binding "Da~Prato" like that but it does not help, writing {Da Prato} does not help either.

What is the problem? My `.tex` file looks like this:

```
\documentclass[article]{imsart}
\usepackage{amsthm,amsmath,natbib}

\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the sort ordering problem write the author name as

```
Da Prato, G.
```

In this way, `bibtex` interprets `Da Prato` as the last name and sorts it under `D`:

[image: Sample output]

There is a very good discussion of specifying names in `bibtex` in the document [Tame the BeaST](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/bibtex/tamethebeast), Chapter 3, section 11, about the `author` field.

```
\documentclass[article]{imsart}
\usepackage{amsthm,amsmath,natbib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

`mybib.bib`:

```
@Article{c,
  author = {Clarke, A.},
  title = {Title},
  journal = {J.},
  year = 1951
}

@Article{e,
  author = {Edmunds, A.},
  title = {Title},
  journal = {J.},
  year = 1950
}

@Article{DPMN92,
author = {Da Prato, G. and Malliavin, P. and Nualart, D.},
title = {Compact families of Wiener functionals},
journal = {C. R. Acad. Sci. Paris},
year = {1992},
OPTkey = {•},
volume = {315},
number = {S\'{e}rie I},
pages = {1287--1291},
OPTmonth = {•},
OPTnote = {•},
OPTannote = {•}
}
```